# QGroupBox Display

Tags: c++, qt

Could some one help me on my code issue

I use 2 Push buttons (in Qt GUi Program) ( 1st, 2nd ) in the bellow code

Initial Image

[image]

1) When I press 1st Push Button, the output in Gbox .. When 1st button pressed

1st push button clicked

[image]

2) When I Press 2nd Push Button the expected output should be like Expected output in Gbox after pressing 2nd button

Expected when 2nd Push button Clicked

[image]

But no changes after pressing 2nd button in Gbox.. No Changes after pressing 2nd Button

No_changes in Gbox_2nd Push Button Selected

[image]

```
#include "test.h"
#include "ui_test.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>

test::test(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::test)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    ui->label_1->hide();
    ui->label_2->hide();
    ui->label_3->hide();
    ui->label_4->hide();
    ui->label_5->hide();
    ui->label_6->hide();
    ui->label_7->hide();

    ui->lineEdit_1->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_2->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_3->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_4->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_5->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_6->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_7->hide();

    ui->Optional->hide();

    Gbox->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Maximum);
    Gbox->setTitle(tr("Gbox_11"));

    mainLayout->addWidget(Gbox);
    setLayout(mainLayout);
}

test::~test()
{
    delete ui;
}

void test::on_1st_clicked()
{
    ui->label_1->show();
    ui->lineEdit_1->show();
    ui->label_1->setText("R : ");

    ui->label_2->show();
    ui->lineEdit_2->show();
    ui->label_2->setText("ID : ");

    ui->label_3->show();
    ui->lineEdit_3->show();
    ui->label_3->setText("X : ");

    ui->label_4->show();
    ui->lineEdit_4->show();
    ui->label_4->setText("Y : ");

    ui->Optional->hide();
    ui->label_5->hide();
    ui->label_6->hide();
    ui->label_7->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_5->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_6->hide();
    ui->lineEdit_7->hide();
    ui->Gbox->show();

    QPushButton *Road = new QPushButton("R");
    QPushButton *Junction = new QPushButton("J");
    QPushButton *Lane = new QPushButton("L");
    QPushButton *Objects = new QPushButton("O");
    QPushButton *Vehical = new QPushButton("V");
    QPushButton *Fupdates = new QPushButton("F");

    glay = new QGridLayout;

    glay->addWidget(Road,0,0,1,1);
    glay->addWidget(Junction,1,1,1,1);
    glay->addWidget(Lane,2,0,1,1);
    glay->addWidget(Objects,3,1,1,1);
    glay->addWidget(Vehical,4,2,1,1);
    glay->addWidget(Fupdates,5,3,1,1);

    setLayout(glay);

    ui->Gbox->setLayout(glay);
}

void test::on_2nd_clicked()
{
    ui->label_1->show();
    ui->lineEdit_1->show();
    ui->label_1->setText("J: ");

    ui->label_2->show();
    ui->lineEdit_2->show();
    ui->label_2->setText("ID : ");

    ui->label_3->show();
    ui->lineEdit_3->show();
    ui->label_3->setText("X : ");

    ui->label_4->show();
    ui->lineEdit_4->show();
    ui->label_4->setText("Y : ");

    ui->Optional->show();
    ui->Gbox->show();

    QPushButton *A = new QPushButton("1");
    QPushButton *B = new QPushButton("2");
    QPushButton *C = new QPushButton("3");
    QPushButton *D = new QPushButton("4");
    QPushButton *E = new QPushButton("5");
    QPushButton *F = new QPushButton("6");

    vlay = new QVBoxLayout;

    vlay->addWidget(A,1);
    vlay->addWidget(B,0);
    vlay->addWidget(C,0);
    vlay->addWidget(D,1);
    vlay->addWidget(E,1);
    vlay->addWidget(F,0);
    setLayout(vlay);

    ui->Gbox->setLayout(vlay);
}

void test::on_Optional_stateChanged()
{
    if(ui->Optional->isChecked())
    {
        ui->label_5->show();
        ui->label_5->setText("P :");

        ui->label_6->show();
        ui->label_6->setText("S 1 :");

        ui->label_7->show();
        ui->label_7->setText("S 2 :");

        ui->lineEdit_5->show();
        ui->lineEdit_6->show();
        ui->lineEdit_7->show();
    }
    else
    {
        ui->label_5->hide();
        ui->label_6->hide();
        ui->label_7->hide();
        ui->lineEdit_5->hide();
        ui->lineEdit_6->hide();
        ui->lineEdit_7->hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the layout `glay` more than once -- you have `setLayout(glay)` followed immediately by `ui->Gbox->setLayout(glay)`.  Likewise with `vlay` in `test::on_2nd_clicked`.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I removed the reparations of glay, vlay and tried but still same issue..QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QGroupBox "Gbox", which already has a layout

Comment: Any better example to know on how to reset the group box when called by different Push Buttons..?

Comment: Instead of replacing layouts, why do not you use QStackedWidget?

Answer (score 0):

Use QLabel::repaint() in each method, and delete previously set layout before setting the new layout for GBox, for exmaple:

```
void test::on_2nd_clicked(){
                    ui->label_1->repaint();
                    ui->label_1->setText("J: ");

                    ui->label_2->repaint();
                    ui->label_2->setText("ID : ");
                    ...
                    ...
 QPushButton *A = new QPushButton("1");
    QPushButton *B = new QPushButton("2");
    QPushButton *C = new QPushButton("3");
    QPushButton *D = new QPushButton("4");
    QPushButton *E = new QPushButton("5");
    QPushButton *F = new QPushButton("6");

    vlay = new QVBoxLayout;


    vlay->addWidget(A,1);
    vlay->addWidget(B,0);
    vlay->addWidget(C,0);
    vlay->addWidget(D,1);
    vlay->addWidget(E,1);
    vlay->addWidget(F,0);
    setLayout(vlay);
    delete glay;
    ui->Gbox->setLayout(vlay);

    }
```

Comment: HI Mohammad Kanan, Thanks for your fast reply, But I am looking for over ridding the group box (Gbox) with new set, When selected by 2nd push-button. repaint() will not work out for me.. so could you suggest other-way..

Comment: @hemanth, you have to delete it, thats all. I will update the anwser